# How to simulate the press of the back key and forward it to foreground application

Tags: android, android-service, back-button, accessibility

Is it possible (And how) to simulate the press of the back key and dispatch / forward it to foreground activity (Which doesn't belong to me)?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that if the activity is foreground, its gonna be the first component to receive the key press event.

Comment: You may be able to do this by implementing an `AccessibilityService`. Otherwise, this should not be possible without root, as it would be a security flaw for one app to inject UI events into another app.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there an example on how to take action (sending back button event) using AccessibilityService? All I found is how to listen to events using AccessibilityService.

Comment: Look at the documentation for `AccessibilityService` regarding `performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK)`

Comment: @DavidWasser Thanks, it always returns false, though I enabled my service via phone settings -> Accessibility, and added needed permissions in AndroidManifest.xml as https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html knowing that I'm calling performGlobalAction from within my class that extends AccessibilityService ... Any thoughts?